# Assistance with Extendable Forms in HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making an online entry form for a martial arts competition. I have got on with everything fine so far. However, there is a part where the user selects how many applicants they wish to input into the competition. The amount that they select will determine the amount of entry rows that come up. I am unsure of how to do this though, would if be possible for any of you geniuses to help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just `<input type="number"`

Comment: But I want the number to determine how many rows, I am not sure how to do this

Comment: with a loop that adds rows based on the number

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding, so could anyone help with with the loop please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, if the end-user selects, say, 8 as the number of people they will be signing up in the competition, the next series of signup elements will correspond with the number of they selected.

Here's my HTML form in my PHP file:

**KarateCompetition.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name = "my-form" id = "my-form">
        <select name = "number-of-participants" id = "number-of-participants">
            <option value = "1">1</option>
            <option value = "2">2</option>
            <option value = "3">3</option>
            <option value = "4">4</option>
            <option value = "5">5</option>
            <option value = "6">6</option>
            <option value = "7">7</option>
            <option value = "8">8</option>
        </select>

        <div id = "entry-details-area">
          <!-- This is where we'll dynamically insert our rows -->
        </div>

    </form>
</body>

<!--First, grab jQuery from Google we need this--> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!--Next, include my logic--> 
<script src = "karate.js"></script>
</html>
```

Next, we'll write our custom logic in "karate.js," and we'll be sure to include that file in our PHP page *after* we have grabbed jQuery from Google (simply inserting the line shown will dynamically include jQuery in your PHP page)

Here's my jQuery (a Javascript library) logic that I'll use to load the HTML elements dynamically when the user selects a specific number of participants:

**karate.js:**

```
  //This is my HTML select element "number-of-participants"
  var participants_selector = $("#number-of-participants"); 

  //This is where I want to add my dynamic HTML input elements
  var entry_details_area = $("#entry-details-area");

  //Each time a new value is chosen, grab their number of participants
  participants_selector.on("change", function()
  {
    //Get the number of participants that the end-user has selected
    var number_of_participants = participants_selector.val();

    //Clear out any previously-appended HTML
    entry_details_area.empty();

    //Next, create a corresponding number of input elements for the number of participants selected.
    for (var i = 0; i < Number(number_of_participants); i++)
    {

      //Remember: Arrays start counting at 0, so to make it human-readable, add +1
      var participant_number = i+1; 

      //Let's add a simple box: "first-name" for each participant
      var entry_form_html = '<p>Participant ' + participant_number + ' first name is: '
                        +'<input name = "first-name-'+participant_number+'" id = "first-name-'+participant_number+'"></p>';

      //Add the HTML for each participant                      
      entry_details_area.append(entry_form_html);
    }//end of loop

  });//end of on-change listener logic
```

To test, [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLg9edrp/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect and just what I was looking for!

Comment: Absolutely! Use this as a bit of a springboard -- I'm excited to see what you come up with once you're able to add your own flavor to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery do append html code dinamically. It would look like this:

```
<table id='tableid'>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
var x = 5; // user input
for(y=0;y<x;Y++){
$('#tableid').append('<html code here to the other <tr> lines>');
}
</script>
```